# Difference between cpprestsdk.v120.winapp and cpprestsdk.v120.windesktop?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

cpprestsdk is a c++ library.

There are several version on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/cpprestsdk/)

Do you know what's the difference between the term 'winapp' and windesktop'?

Comment: You need the winapp flavor when you target WinRT (Store and Phone apps), windesktop fits the way it has been done for the past 23 years.

Comment: Cool, that means windesktop is the traditional desktop (win32, MFC) application version. I will use it then.